# Hiding code or blocking code editing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I developed a software in Python and this software has some user's restrictions. Once I don't know how to block my users to open and change my code, it becomes very useless if they just delete a line from my code and then have permissions that they are not allowed. Is there any way to protect my  software from changing or even block the code visualization?

Answer (score 1):

Distribute only your Python compiled `.pyc` files.

Do not distribute your Python source code `.py` files.

http://www.curiousefficiency.org/posts/2011/04/benefits-and-limitations-of-pyc-only.html